# Error in Column operation while using techincal analysis library of python

Tags: python, pandas, technical-indicator

I am trying to calculate 5 day moving averages using a technical analysis library of python:

```py
import pandas as pd
import ta
df = pd.read_csv("sbin.csv")                             
df['EMA'] = ta.trend.EMAIndicator(df['High'],5)
```

When i check values of `df['EMA']` - i get the following:

```
0       <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
1       <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
2       <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
3       <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
4       <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
                            ...                      
1370    <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
1371    <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
1372    <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
1373    <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
1374    <ta.trend.EMAIndicator object at 0x11ef6c520>
Name: EMA, Length: 1375, dtype: object
```

The input SBIN CSV file looks like this:

[image: SBIN CSV file , first few rows and columns]

Can anyone point what i am doing wrong?

Sincere thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("sbin.csv")                             
ema5 = ta.trend.EMAIndicator(df['High'],5)
df['EMA'] = ema5_ema_indicator()
```